# Issue with recursively displaying set of questions and subquestions with Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, recursion

I have a set of data structured like this:

```js
[{
    question: true,
    title: 'Some question text',
    node: [{
        answer: true,
        title: 'Yes',
        node: []
    }, {
        answer: true,
        title: 'No',
        node: [{
            subquestion: true,
            title: 'Some subquestion text',
            node: []
        }]
    }, {
        answer: true,
        title: 'Maybe',
        node: []
    }]
}, {}]
```

I have managed to display all questions, answers and subquestions with a recursive Vue component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div
            class="single-container"
            v-for="question in questions"
            :key="question.id">
            <div>
                <p class="question"
                   v-if="question.question || question.subquestion">
                   {{ question.title }}
                </p>
                <div v-else class="answer">
                    <input
                        type="radio"
                        :id="question.id"
                        :name="question.parentId"
                    />
                    <label :for="question.id">{{ question.title }}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <QuestionsTree :questions="question.node" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I also handle cases when/which subquestion should be displayed or not, based on the parent answer.
However, the way this works means that a subquestion will be outputed directly below the answer, because that subquestion is nested inside that answer.

---

**Here is an image to show what I mean**

[image: here is an image to show what I mean]

**What I'm trying to achieve is this: all answers stay inline, no matter what you answer**

[image: all answers stay inline, no matter what you answer]

---

Is this possible with my data set? If so, how? Thanks and I hope I was clear enough.